# Saving openAI TTS API response with R programming

Tags: r, text-to-speech, openai-api, httr

HTTR2 does a great job of calling the OpenAI TTS (text to speech) API.  However, I am having trouble saving the response from the API in an audio format. Since the API is "new" and Rpackages have not been updated to integrate it, I have to use HTTR2.

I clearly see tons of ways to do it in Python, but what command should I use to save an audio response?

So far I have tried the "av" package. Ultimately, I would like to get something similar to the `stream_to_file()` function in Python used by others to perform this task.

Thanks

I was thinking the "av" package would let me convert everthing to a mp3 with `av_audio_convert(response)` and `av_audio_convert(response$body)`.  I get an error.  `Error in path.expand(path) : invalid 'path' argument.`

Similarly, I tried pretty much everything with the read functions of the package "av".

The "response" from OpenAI display the following message.

```
<httr2_response>
POST https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/speech
Status: 200 OK
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Body: In memory (899520 bytes)
```

Comment: Presumably the response body is binary data in mp3 format, though you'll need to check the API documentation to confirm this. If that's the case you can just use `writeBin` to write the `content` of the response to disk with an appropriate mp3 filename.

Comment: What exactly does your calling code look like? The `req_perform` function has a `path=` argument to save the results directly to disk rather than loading into memory first. The response indicates it's sending your a file with content type "audio/mpeg"

Comment: According to [the docs](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-to-speech) the default response format is "mp3", but other formats like "opus", "aac", or "flac" are available, so you should be able to just save the content to disk as an mp3 directly unless you have specified a different format.

Comment: Thanks a lot Allan and MrFlick, both of your solutions work.  This is very helpful, thanks a lot !!!!